# New line Command (\n) was not working while handline files with TomCat

Tags: java, file, jakarta-mail, readfile

I am trying a to send a mail by reading contents from text file.

File I am trying to read

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

I have tested the code with JUnit and I get the mail with same formatting as in the text file.

Output mail using Junit

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

But when deployed in Tomcat, I get a mail with the text but new lines are not getting recognized.

Output mail when using tomcat server

```
Line 1Line 2Line 3
```

Code that I am using to read the contents of the file.

```
private String readFile(String pathname) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(pathname);
        StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int) file.length());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        try {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine() + lineSeparator);
            }
            return fileContents.toString();
        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
```

I have put the server in debug mode and I can see that new line is getting appended in `fileContents.toString()`

I am not sure what I am missing. Anything related to character set? I am not sure....

Comment: As I assume lineSeparator value may not get as you expect in tomcat.

Comment: Linux and Windows have different line separators

Comment: How are you reading the email? Could be your mail client clobbering the new lines.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov I am developing and testing in Windows server. But the code will finally deployed in linux server. So what can be done to handle this?

Comment: @Perception I am not reading any email. I am trying to send email by reading a text file. I have given the code that I use for reading the file. It is working fine with Junits. But not with tomcat. So I think there may not be issue with mail client

Comment: is there any html in the loop ? html doesn't care about crlf, just need <br>

Comment: @nullix There is No HTML. Its all plain text.

Comment: on what system are you running tomcat ? your code replace syste-agnostic separator to system-dependant one, this of server. If service is linux (lf) and client is windows (crlf) ... bingo

Comment: @om39a - well, you are reading the email somewhere right? In order to verify that it was sent by your program?

Comment: @Perception Yes. I do read the mails. But how it is related to this issue?

Comment: @nullix I am using testing in windows. Based on your suggestion and with ref to [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) I replaced `System.getProperty("line.separator")` with `\r\n` _I ve added carriage return_ but still I get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with clue from Perception and nullix. How the mail is read and the HTML.

In my case, I was testing by sending mail from a mail client which was sending out **"text/html"** type messages to my application. So when I am replying to that mail, the reply mail was also with "text/html" format. Hence the **/n** or what ever line feed type that I used was omitted.

So while reading the mail I read only **"text/plain"** mime type. So while replying to this mail, I could get the new line printed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the way you're reading the mail output makes you think the newline isn't there. For example if you write '\n' as newline, and open the file on windows notepad, then it would appear as if the newline is not there.

Using more sophisticated text viewer like Notepad++ where you can see the whitespace character might help